# Why do op-amps have labeled terminals?

Tags: operational-amplifier

For some type of op-amp circuits, the inverting terminal is placed on top, while on others it's at the bottom (i.e. inverting vs non-inverting amplifier). I don't understand the convention - how do you decide what to label each terminal? Aren't either labels valid since both terminals are equivalent?

Comment: One terminal is the inverting input, and the other is the non-inverting input. They are NOT equivalent.

Comment: @KyranF What's the difference between the two terminals? If I have an OP Amp circuit and I switch the signs of the OP Amp nothing would change since the analysis of OP amps seem to be independent of the sign.

Comment: the logic inside an OPAMP compares A with B. The actual structure of transistors inside physically makes the inputs different, you cannot say they are the same.

Comment: Also, the analysis is very different with feedback too, the transfer functions and resulting Gain equations are very different depending which of the two inputs are used.

Comment: "The analysis of Opamps" whatever it is, is in error if it concludes there is no difference.

Comment: Okay, old question, but ... the "analysis of opamps" that the OP means would be that the voltage and current at the input are both zero. Since the voltage is zero, the polarity does not matter - in fact, it is meaningless. In this sense the opamp can operate even with strictly zero voltage. So the analysis does not distinguish. However, the stability is the other issue. If the voltage is slightly off zero, then one configuration with run out of control and the other wont. A real opamp is just very high, not infinite gain. Hence this needs to be added to the analysis.

Answer (score 8):

An individual op-amp will have *one* non-inverting input (usually denoted with a `+` symbol) and *one* inverting input (usually denoted with a `-`).

They are *very much* **not** equivalent. As their description makes apparent, one inverts it's input value, and the other does not.

Now, with regard to the *drawn symbol*, which is on top is generally a function of what will make the schematic clearer and/or easier to draw. They're both valid ways to draw an op-amp, though the circuit *has* to accommodate which connection is where.

You decide what to label each terminal based on the part datasheet, which will tell you which physical pin maps to what function of the device.

---

Fundamentally, an op-amp's output is the difference between the input pins, multiplied by the op-amps gain (ignoring the non-idealities of op-amps for the moment).

\$ V_{OUT} = GAIN * (V_{+} - V_{-})\$

Now, let's take the two simplest possible configurations:

- `-` input is grounded (e.g. 0V), input signal is on `+` input:
  Circuit behaviour is: \$ V_{OUT} = GAIN * (V_{+} - 0)\$, which simplifies to \$ V_{OUT} = GAIN * V_{+}\$
- `+` input is grounded (e.g. 0V), input signal is on `-` input:
  Circuit behaviour is: \$ V_{OUT} = GAIN * (0 - V_{-})\$, which simplifies to \$ V_{OUT} = GAIN * -V_{-}\$

In the latter case, the input voltage is \$-V_{-}\$, which has the effect of *inverting* the input voltage on the `-` across the voltage at the `+` pin (in this case ground, so the term simplifies out). The fact that you invert the sign of the input is why the inverting input is *called* the inverting input \$-\$.

I don't know how you're analyzing an op-amp circuit that you are not seeing a difference when you swap the inputs, but you're apparently doing it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "inverts" it's input? Does it make it negative?

Comment: You sound like you **really** need to [read up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) on what an op-amp *is*. I don't know why you think switching the pins does not affect the analysis, that is incorrect.

Comment: In a real OP AMP I get why it matters. The gain is a function of the difference, so the difference is obvious. In an ideal OP Amp they have the same voltage; therefore switching them wouldn't change anything since the voltage assigned to each terminal would remain the same. For example, in this derivation of an inverting OP AMP, what part would change if the signs on the OP AMP were switched? http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_2.html

Comment: They have the same voltage *because of the feedback network*, not because it's a fundamental property of op-amps. With an ideal op-amp, you have a theoretically infinite gain, but infinity * 1 != infinity * -1.

Comment: Why would it be 1*infinity or -1*infinity. Wouldn't it be 0*infinity = -0*infinity? Since (V+ - V-) = 0 = (V- - V+)?

Comment: In your ideal linked page, as long as everything was maintained at 0V, it would theoretically just sit there, whether you flip the pins or not. However, if you did flip the pins, and then *applied input*, depending on the sign of the input, the output would either swing to the positive or negative rail, because you now have positive feedback.

Comment: However, an op-amp where you are not applying input is useless, so aside from the thought-experiment, it's irrelevant.

Comment: What you're asking is if you wire `Pin B` to `Pin A`, is that different then wiring `Pin A` to `Pin B`. Obviously, there is no difference assuming they're both held at the exact same voltage. It's when they're at *different* voltages that things are relevant. The feedback network of an op-amp works by measuring the difference between the pins, and modifying the output value to reduce the difference as much as possible. If you cannot have a difference between the pins, (infinitesimal as it may be in the case of ideal op-amps), it cannot work.

Comment: An ideal op amp can't really work, because with infinite gain, there is no error signal to amplify -- and therefore there can be no output (because output is determined by the error voltage). "Ideal op amp" is just a heuristic we use to simplify analysis of a control loop circuit, by **removing the entire op amp** and just modeling what the feedback network must be doing -- assuming that the op amp is in stable, convergent, negative feedback. The `+` and `-` must be close enough, within Vsupply/GAIN, if the output isn't saturated.

Comment: @dfg: \$-\infty \neq +\infty\$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). You could probably do something involving [infinitesimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) to make sense of it, but that's not really your question (and I don't know the math well enough to explain it anyways).

Answer (score 2):

They are not equialent because the op amp has to know WHICH WAY to adjust the output if the pins are not sitting at the same voltage.  If you switch them, then the op amp output will simply zip over to one rail or the other and stay put.  Op amps are generally designed with a nergative feedback loop.  In this case, the outp of the op amp is fed back around, modified in some way, and then subtracted from the input.  If the result is negative, the op amp lowers its output voltage.  If you swap the inputs, the feedback will be positive instead of negative and the op amp output will be driven to one rail or the other.  This can be useful when you want hysteresis (e.g. schmitt trigger).

Answer (score 0):

The terminals are not equivalent. You are using one of the rules of opamps incorrectly.

One of the rules is that the inputs (inverting and non inverting) are equivalent.

That is only true if feedback is used.

The op amp will look at its input and then adjust the output pin accordingly such that the two terminals are equivalent.

If no feedback is used, it will swing the output voltage to the rails as it tries to "balance" then inputs but it never will.

Answer (score 0):

Differential amplifier substracts two signals.

Substract is noncommutative operation. You cannot swap operators (or signals) and have same result.

\$4 - 1 \neq 1 - 4\$

[Commutative property in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property#Noncommutative_operations_in_mathematics)